# Print String only if it contains Letters, or Numbers, a space or comma

Tags: java

EDIT,

Would anyone know the code,  that will print a String only if it contains, letters or numbers, or a space, or comma.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: OK my bad, i need to only print the string if contains letters or numbers

Comment: Perhaps you would like to [edit] your question to include a [mre] and an accurate description of in what way your code is not doing what you want it do.

Comment: You have two contradictory statements in your question. First, you want it to print if it contains letters and number; the second if it only contains letters and numbers. And the string won't print, because it contains spaces.

Comment: *"if it contains, Letters, or Numbers, or ','"* is not the opposite of *"contains a value that isn't a letter(upper case or lower), a number, or ','"*, e.g. both are true for input `"Wrong!"`.

Comment: The code you have given now doesn't print because you have `^` (which means "not") in your regular expression. (.....) And now you've added a space back into your string so it doesn't match your requriements any more.

Answer (score -1):

You should try this regular expression:

```
String example = "abC*D005";

if (example.matches("^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$"))
{
    System.out.println(example);
}
```

Comment: Try with an another string, for example: String example = "abCD005";

Comment: And the "[a-zA-Z0-9]+" is good enough, because the matches returns only true if the WHOLE string can be matched.

Comment: how do we edit this to allow for spaces and commas?

Comment: "[a-zA-Z0-9,\\s]+"

Comment: Hi, sorry one last question, can we add a backspace'\' to this? the string contains '\n'